# JavaFX / ScalaFX - Change text color of disabled TextArea?

Tags: textarea, javafx, scalafx

I have a GUI with some TextArea elements to display information. As the GUI shall react to keyevents I added a EventHandler to the scene element. Because I didn't want to add one EventHandler to each textarea I disabled them to prevent that they are focused because then the scene's eventhandler doesn't work anymore. Now I have the problem the text is displayed in gray and not in black anymore eventhough I changed that in the css file. Do you have any ideas why the text isn't black and how i could fix that?

Here is some code:

```
private val scene =
  new Scene {
    stylesheets.add("css/style.css")
    onKeyTyped = (new EventHandler[KeyEvent] {
      def handle(event: KeyEvent) {
        ...
      }
    })
  ...
}

private val description = new TextArea{    
  text = "some text"
  wrapText = true
  disable = true 
  styleClass.add("txtarea")      
  maxHeight = 400
}


.txtarea:disabled{  
  -fx-font-size: 18pt;
  -fx-text-fill: #000000;
  -fx-prompt-text-fill: #000000;
  -fx-opacity: 1.0;
  -fx-background-color: white;  
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You also need to provide style for the scroll pane embedded in the TextArea:

```
.txtarea .scroll-pane:disabled{
  -fx-opacity: 1.0;
}
```